# QGIS inputting spatial reference data

Tags: qgis

I am trying to add a .csv file into QGIS but the spatial reference data has not been split into lat/long, how do I get GIS to understand this sort of data, or is there anyway I can mass split up the data, as I have 10000 points to add.

[image: Spatial reference example]

Comment: Welcome to GSE ! Can you provide a short abstract of your .csv data ? What is the `Grid Reference` field referring to ? It's not lat/long or X/Y coordinates, is-it sort of MGRS grid ?

Comment: Hi Katherine, those look like ordnance survey grid references. Try the TomBio plugin - it can turn them in to the grid squares that the values represent. Help pages for the plugin are here: https://www.fscbiodiversity.uk/qgisplugin/v2